# is this conclusion true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a factor Von Neumann algebra and $\Phi$ is a map on  $\mathcal{A}$ which is injective and surjective and $\Phi(0)=0$. If $A, B, C \in \mathcal{A}$  and $\Phi(A+B)=\Phi(A)+\Phi(C)$, can we conclude that $B=C$? If yes, how can i prove it? and if no, is there any example to reject it?
thanks for your help.

Comment: Shall $\Phi$ be continuous or something? Without _any_ further restrictions, there's no way it can be true.

Comment: Von Neumann algebra is known, but factor Neumann what that means?

Comment: there is no other restriction on $\Phi$. Is there any example to reject that statement or any restriction on $\Phi$ that help me to prove it?

Comment: @Adelafif, factor means that the center of space is $\mathbb{C}I$.

Comment: Let $\Phi(x) = x$ if $x \notin \mathbb{C}^\times I$, and $\Phi(\lambda I) = \lambda^{-1} I$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^\times$.